# Read value from an fcurve at specific frames

Tags: scripting

I need to get the values from an fcurve at specific frames using a script.These frames do not necessarily have keys on them.
Lets say I have an object selected and I need to retrieve the y position at frame 7. (I am not a python coder, this is to be used in conjunction with the Animation Nodes addon.)
Is it possible?

Thanks!
Sahin

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you're asking:

```
object.animation_data.action.fcurves[1].evaluate(7)
```

In this example, fcurves[1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/how-to-get-a-property-value-not-in-current-frame/3248#3248) would access the Y location curve in the collection of fcurves belonging to 'object'. And the Evaluate function will return the value of fcurves[1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/how-to-get-a-property-value-not-in-current-frame/3248#3248) at frame 7.

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/how-to-get-a-property-value-not-in-current-frame/3248#3248) has a more thorough answer.

Comment: Since the answer linked can `D.actions['CubeAction'].fcurves.find("scale", index=1)` to find the y scale fcurve for instance.