# get position difference of the object from current frame and previous frame through python

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, mathematics

I have an animated object

I am searching a way to calculate the difference in the position of the object from current frame and a previous frame and if the difference is not big enough i want to keep previous position

cant find a way to do it :(

Comment: this should help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106574/read-value-from-an-fcurve-at-specific-frames

Comment: thank you Chris